# Add popular blog posts to the Stack Exchange home page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, blog-overflow

If popular blog posts were included in the [homepage of stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com/), then popular content from the blogs would be much more visible to the users of Stack Exchange.

The blog posts would be styled differently than regular questions, so people could tell them apart. Their place on the homepage would be determined according to a similar algorithm that sorts the questions.

Comment: I *completely* misread this. This would work fine on the main SE site's homepage.

Comment: A redesign of the stackexchange.com homepage is in the works.

Comment: **Oh noez!** You're going to move my cheese *again*?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "hot?"  And if you mean what I *think* you mean, I'm all for it.

Comment: @Emmett out of curiosity, what else are you going to add in the redesign?

Comment: a couple animated gifs and a `<marquee>`

Comment: no flash intro?

Comment: There ought to be an intro animation of Bubbles dancing around or something...

Comment: @Jeff [surprisingly prescient :)](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: @Emmett: Ooh, that's pretty sweet.  Next up, Stack Overflow with something similar!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) homepage now shows 5 most recent blog posts in the bottom left section. The blog posts are ordered by *date*, not *popularity*, but I'll call this [status-completed] any way.

Also, we've added [stackexchange.com/blogs](https://stackexchange.com/blogs), which replaces blogoverflow.com.

Comment: You did a great job with the redesign.